# Replacing characters in entire Pandas dataframe with values from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a German csv file that was incorrectly encoded. I want to convert the characters back to utf-8 using a dictionary. I thought what I was doing was correct, but when I print the DF, nothing has changed. Here's my code:

```py
DATA_DIR = 'C:\\...'

translations = {
    'Ã¶': 'oe',
    'Ã¼': 'ue',
    'ÃŸ': 'ss',
    'Ã¤': 'ae',
    'â‚¬': '€',
    'Ã„': 'Ae',
    'Ã–': 'Oe',
    'Ãœ': 'Ue'
}


def cleanup():
    for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(DATA_DIR)):
        if not file.lower().endswith('.csv'):
            continue

        data_utf = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, file), header=3, index_col=None, skiprows=0-2)

        data_utf.replace(translations, inplace=True)

        print(data_utf)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cleanup()
```

I also tried

```py
        for before, after in translations.items():
            data_utf.replace(before, after)
```

within the function, and directly putting the translations in the replace itself. This process works if I specify the column in which to replace the characters, however. What do I need to do to apply these translations to the whole dataframe, as well as to the dataframe column headers? Thanks!

Comment: reopened, because more complicated - also replace by columns values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `regex=True` for replace in substrings, for columns is possible convert values to `Series` by [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html) and then use `replace`:

```
data_utf = pd.DataFrame({'raÃœing':['Ã¶saÃ¼s','Ã„ dd Ã–','Ã–Ã„']})

translations = {
    'Ã¶': 'oe',
    'Ã¼': 'ue',
    'ÃŸ': 'ss',
    'Ã¤': 'ae',
    'â‚¬': '€',
    'Ã„': 'Ae',
    'Ã–': 'Oe',
    'Ãœ': 'Ue'
}

data_utf.replace(translations, inplace=True, regex=True)
data_utf.columns = data_utf.columns.to_series().replace(translations, regex=True)
print (data_utf)
    raUeing
0   oesaues
1  Ae dd Oe
2      OeAe
```

Comment: Great, that worked! I knew it had to be simple. However, it doesn't change the column headers. Is there anything special I have to do to get the translation to cover the headers?

Comment: @trashdragon - Can you add to question is necessary also replace columns names?

Comment: The `to_series()` part was giving me an 'unresolved attribute reference', so to get it to work I had to use ```data_utf.rename(columns={'ArtikelÂ­bezeichnung': 'Artikel bezeichnung'})```, though this is unfortunately hard-coded.

Comment: @trashdragon - What is your pandas version? Tested in pandas 0.25.0

Comment: my version is 0.25.2. Perhaps there's an error with Pycharm because when I run it, it works, but it's still marking as unresolved. Either way it works so thank you :)